# Database Engine like MS Access in Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, database

I want a Database Engine like MS Access in Ubuntu where I can easily create queries.

If Ubuntu has an application, please tell me.

Comment: https://www.mysql.com// https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: LibreOffice, the well-known alternative of MS Office, also has a database application: https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the LibreOffice "Base" application, there is also [Apache OpenOffice "Base"](https://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html). As mentioned on the Product page, "Base delivers native support drivers for a variety of multi-user database engines: MySQL, Adabas D, MS Access and PostgreSQL."

[A related page](https://www.openoffice.org/dba/) on the Apache OpenOffice site also says: 
"Starting as mere database access functionality of the other OpenOffice.org applications, Base has, with OpenOffice 3, evolved to an own database application. It allows you to access data on an external database of your choice (for instance MySQL, PostgreSQL, and many others), plus bundles the HSQLDB database engine, this way allowing you to kick-start with your own database."

Comment: there is no advantage of apache openoffice base over libreoffice base though.